# How to await for the appendchild

Tags: javascript, angular

i have a method called addcomponent which takes a component_factory and a target node  as arguments

this dragdropservice.ts

```js
addComponent(componentClass: ComponentFactory<any>, target) {
    let componentRef: ComponentRef<any> = this.container.createComponent(componentClass);
    setTimeout(() => {
        target.appendChild(window.document.getElementById(componentRef.instance.index))
    }, 0);
}
```

I'm using this method in dragging and dropping components and that's work fine but my problem is when invoking this method to reproduce saved components from the database . Some components are used as targets but the problem is with the settimeout . how to await for the ending of the setimeout  to add the next component

layoutcomposition.ts

```
ngOnInit() {


   this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe((paramMap: ParamMap) => {
  var id = paramMap.get('id');
  if (id) {
    console.log(id)
    this.savestate.getcomponents(id).subscribe(
      data => {




        for (var i = 0; i < data['data'].length; i++) {

          if (data['data'][i].selector === 'app-col') {


            var colcomponent = new Col(this.factoryResolver)
            if (data['storetargetid'][i] === "content") { 
             this.dragDropService.addComponent(colcomponent.component,document.getElementById("content"))

            }
else {
                  var arr =data['storetargetid'][i].split("-",2)
                  this.dragDropService.addComponent(colcomponent.component,document.getElementById(arr[0]).children[0].children[arr[1]])

            }
          }



        }
```

storetargetid is where i'm storing the ids of the targets when dropping components

Comment: post more context, so it can be made clear how to help you better.  Basically you need to wrap it in a promise, and then `await` it where you need it.

Comment: AppendChild is synchronous Ithink, so right after the appendChild call you are ready to add the next component. Unless the next one depends on the previous component having gone though angular life cycle?

Comment: I modified the question and i added some code hope that it will be clear

Comment: Please use code formatter before posting, impossible to read :( (also set tabs to use spaces instead of actual tabs, this will make the indentation consistent across platforms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use setTimeout to simulate asynchronous operations (unless you need to support legacy browsers).  In this case just adding `async` in front of the function is enough:

```
async addComponent(componentClass: ComponentFactory<any>, target) {
    let componentRef: ComponentRef<any> = this.container.createComponent(componentClass);
    target.appendChild(window.document.getElementById(componentRef.instance.index));
}
```

You indicate the setTimeout is meant to deal with a DOM issue.  There are some browser bugs that have to be handled this way, but I'd check to make sure it's not due to a race condition or async problem, which you should fix directly.
You can wrap the setTimeout in a Promise so you can await it.

```
addComponent(componentClass: ComponentFactory<any>, target) {
    let componentRef: ComponentRef<any> = this.container.createComponent(componentClass);
    return new Promise((res,rej) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        target.appendChild(window.document.getElementById(componentRef.instance.index));
        res();
      }, 0);
    });
}
```

Note that the function inside the subscribe has been made `async`.  Now you can put `await` in front of the call to addComponent to make it wait for the operation to finish before continuing.

```
ngOnInit() {


   this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe((paramMap: ParamMap) => {
  var id = paramMap.get('id');
  if (id) {
    console.log(id)
    this.savestate.getcomponents(id).subscribe(
      async (data) => {




        for (var i = 0; i < data['data'].length; i++) {

          if (data['data'][i].selector === 'app-col') {


            var colcomponent = new Col(this.factoryResolver)
            if (data['storetargetid'][i] === "content") { 
             await this.dragDropService.addComponent(colcomponent.component,document.getElementById("content"))

            }
else {
                  var arr =data['storetargetid'][i].split("-",2)
                  await this.dragDropService.addComponent(colcomponent.component,document.getElementById(arr[0]).children[0].children[arr[1]])

            }
          }



        }
```

Comment: when i delete the settiemout the appendchild don't work anymore , so i can't put any component inside other one

Comment: I've added the Promise wrapping of setTimeout.  But judging from what you're saying it sounds more like an async problem with your Angular triggering of these functions possibly not being in the order that you expect it to.  The setTimeout is probably just hiding a race condition present in your code.     You should add a breakpoint in your debugger here to make sure the DOM is in the state that you expect it to be in.  Or use console.log to inspect it.

Comment: In fact, I'd guess that now that the await fixes the control flow to wait before continuing, it will no longer work, because the reason it was working with setTimeout is that latter code was executing before your setTimeout resolved, allowing the appendChild to work.

Comment: By now it fixes the problem of appendchild thank you bro